# How to find similar sounding words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm writing a specialized (in food realm) multi-lingual search engine.
I use python and nltk libraries.
I have quite a big database of recipes for all cultures I want to support.

I'm asking if and how it is possible to be able to find in my indexed words corpus a *wrong spelled* word...
For example, in Italian, to look for "couscous" word, many users would say/write "cus cus", or "cuscus"...

In synthesis, this is an example of how I tokenize my index of lexemes for search:

```
import re
import nltk
import string

corpus = 'italian'
stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.ItalianStemmer()
stopWords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(corpus)

# tokenize the sentence(s)
wordTokenizedList = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)

# remove punctuation and everything lower case
wordTokenizedListNoPunct = [ word.lower() for word in wordTokenizedList if word not in string.punctuation ]

# remove stop words
wordTokenizedListNoPunctNoStopWords = [ word for word in wordTokenizedListNoPunct if word not in stopWords ]

# snowball stemmer 
wordTokenizedListNoPunctNoStopWordsStems = [ stemmer.stem(i) for i in wordTokenizedListNoPunctNoStopWords ]

return wordTokenizedListNoPunctNoStopWordsStems
```

Should I prepare my index someway differently to reach my goal?

Any additional remark about a more complete flow in the text analysis for tokenization should be welcome, of course... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd just use a database with elastic search capabilities.

PROS:

1. They already solve these kind of issues
2. WAY faster
3. Safer

And well, a long etcetera as you can imagine.

Is really easy to connect Python with SQLite and the FTS5 [(Full Text Search)](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) module works great!

I'll highly recommend to watch the following video for you to get an idea if this will suit your solution :) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXMA_2dEMO0)

Comment: This is a very good suggestion. Though, unfortunately, FTS5 does not seem to support languages other than English...

Comment: Yeah, that's a pitty, the porter tokenizer on the FTS5 module only works in English and usually that's the case in other DBs too.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did choose follow @vgenovpy advise, and went with a full ElasticSearch solution (https://www.elastic.co/).
It is open source, well opinionated, offers search, observability and security features out of the box. Analyze, filter and stemming rules are available for very many languages. And more, it has a very kind and responsive community who helped me with some beginner questions...
I am very happy with it.
Of course learning curve is quite steep, but after a week or so, I can say I already feel ES APIs quite confortable and "easy".